# How do you add dynamically a view from xml file, I want to add TableRow in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, tablerow

I am trying to add table row dynamically in my activity. The table row is in the relative layout. It looks fine but don't know where I am going wrong. Below is my code

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    RelativeLayout RLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);
    TableRow tableRow = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.TableRow);
    for(int i = 1; i <3; i++)
        RLayout.addView(tableRow); //My code is crashing here
}
```

And the main.xml as follows

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  >
  <TableRow
  android:id="@+id/TableRow"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  >
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/Text"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Text"
  >
  </TextView>
  </TableRow>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's crashing because that `TableRow` is already in the layout. If you want to add some dynamically you have to create it programmatically, that is:

```
// PSEUDOCODE
TableRow newRow = new TableRow(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(/*....*/);
newRow.setLayoutParams(lp);

relLayout.add(newRow);
```

Actually `TableRow` should be used inside `TableLayout`.

If you want to use something more than once, you can use the inflate technique. You need to create an xml layout that includes the only part that you want to repeat (so your `TableRow` and its children), and then:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = 
              (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
```

Now `inflated` contains the layout you specified. Instead of `null`, you might want to put there the layout to which attach the inflated one. Every time you need a new element like that, you would have to inflate it the same way.

(You should always report the error you get when it crashes)

**------ EDIT -----**

ok now i see, this is your code:

```
RelativeLayout RLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);
TableRow tableRow = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.TableRow);

for(int i = 1; i <4; i++) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, tableRow);
}
```

this way you're inflating your whole layout inside the original TableRow.

You should have a `row.xml` layout like this, together with the `main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/TableRow"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  >
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/Text"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Text"
  />
  </TableRow>
```

and then inflate it like this:

```
RelativeLayout RLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);

for(int i = 1; i <4; i++) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, RLayout);
}
```

see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I will get back after trying it out.

Comment: wow It works and now I understand about layout inflater as well. Thanks.

Comment: There is one problem happening. The added rows append each other horizontally. I want the new row to come below the previous. I thought I might just have to change the orientation but it is not so...

Comment: @Shaista are you adding them to a TableLayout instead of a RelativeLayout? if for some (strange) reason you're still on RelativeLayout remember that you have to attach to each child you add the LayoutParams, and set them up to explain how you want them to dispose.

Comment: here is the code  RelativeLayout RLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout);
        TableRow tableRow = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.TableRow);     
        
        for(int i = 1; i <4; i++)
        {
         LayoutInflater inflater = 
                (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, tableRow);
         
        }
is this not enough? do I have to use new
addview(view,params);

Comment: I'm sorry you're right, inflated views just get their layout params from xml. Anyway you should really consider using TableLayout in place of RelativeLayout. RelativeLayout are better in fixed layouts, because it has complex layout params (you would have to specify that each new child lies below the previous, and this is automatic in a vertical linearlayout and in tablelayout)

Comment: Even if I use Table Layout instead of Relative layout. I see the same problem.

Comment: Looks like if I just could have a new line option. And you are right will use TableLayout but unfortunately that has also not helped, I tried with linear layout too, but not there too. :(

Comment: Hey bigstones, it does not work with Relative layout but it does work with tablelayout. Atleast you helped me find the real problem. Thanks a lot. you guys are doing great job.