# Get only parameters from xml for dynamically created views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a problem that sounds like this: I am creating a set of views dynamically and all of them have the same parameters.

```
TableLayout tab = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.itemsTableLayout);
...

row = new TableRow(this);
row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tab.addView(row);
```

**The question is:** How can I get parameters from xml for this layout. I mean how can I use something like getLayoutParams from xml?

Thanks, 
Arkde

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Won't inflating view from xml do the trick?

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

For those you need help regarding the problem I had, see this:

[How do you add dynamically a view from xml file, I want to add TableRow in RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285274/how-do-you-add-dynaically-a-view-from-xml-file-i-want-to-add-tablerow-in-relativ)

In that post inflating is explained so it's easy to understand :)